# Yii2: Select last 3 rows of each item

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model

Given these tables/fields:

people:

```
id
socialID
name
```

peopleStats:

```
id
socialID
drVisitsAmount
receipAmounts
operationsAmount
```

Im trying to get last 3 records from peopleStats (ordered by id DESC) for a given array of socialIDs (3 records per each socialID):

```
$dummyData = PeopleStats::find()
            ->where(['socialID' => $socialIDs])
            ->groupBy(['socialID'])
            ->orderBy(['id' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(3)
            ->all();
```

but i just get 3 records and not 3 per each. How can i get this data?

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Use Join with "people" table to get your required result.

Comment: Tried that but still receiving just 3 items:

$dummyData = PeopleStats::find()
            ->where(['peopleStats.socialID' => $socialIDs])
            ->joinWith('people')
            ->groupBy(['people.socialID'])
            ->orderBy(['peopleStats.id' => SORT_DESC])
            ->limit(3)
            ->all();

Comment: what does your desired SQL look like? Also, there is an "->offset" method to skip items.

Comment: use `->asArray()->all()` instead of just `->all()` this might work.